# S3 ajax request to Lambda API

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, aws-lambda

I'm trying to figure out the best way to run this:

Having hosted a simple website with a JS form in S3 bucket, I want to `Post` the filled form with `ajax` to an https endpoint which would trigger my `Lambda` to do something with it. Is there a way how to make it secure like allow only that S3 bucket to trigger the `Lambda` (so no other post request can do it?) or to have S3 sign it with some AWS cool authentication between their own services?

I've been googling it for quite some time, but not sure what is the best approach. Thanks a lot for suggestions

Comment: If you're looking to do a HTTP POST I'd assume you would be using AWS API Gateway to do so.  You can wrap that with authentication using https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/

Comment: yh, everything is within AWS :) I will have a look into it! thanks!